# accessing a file in the root folder from a subfolder

Tags: javascript, php, html

my folder structure is as follows:

```
sample/register
```

i have a file in `sample` folder named `index.html` .i want to redirect to this file from a file  within `register` folder.how can i do that? this is what i have done.But the problem is that i have a file within `register` folder named `index.html` and its getting redirected to this folder.how do i mention the root folder?

```
<li><a id="register" href="index.html">Back</a></li>
```

Comment: `href="/index.html"`?

Comment: Are you looking for a JS hint at how to redirect just for the relative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where your root folder is `href="/index.html"` may work or just going up one folder with `href="../index.html"`